# Changing default width/size of the auto-filter popup in Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2010

In [Excel 2007 autofilter](http://www.contextures.com/xlautofilter01.html), is it possible to change the default width of the popup?  I'm working with spreadsheets that have rather long values in some cells and I always have to resize the box before changing the filter.

[image: Screenshot of the Excel 2007 autofilter popup dialog]

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, I think the only way to do this is by creating a custom AutoFilter pop up box using UserForms and VBA and that might be more trouble than it's worth.